# Is there a GUI builder for ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, user-interface, extjs4, sencha-architect

Back in the day, when `ExtJS` was at `2` and it was completely `FOSS`, there were a bunch of online `GUI builders` that really helped drafting your GUI.

During `ExtJS 3` iirc, `ExtJS` was ackquired by *Sencha*. They sold a steeply priced commercial product called `Ext Designer` for this purpose. But for FOSS projects, the `ExtJS2` GUI design tools still worked.

Now `ExtJS` is at `4` and most/all(?) of the online GUI builders have disappeared. The one I found for offline use didn't work with `ExtJS4`. *Sencha* released their new commercial product `Sencha Architect` for designing `ExtJS4` GUIs.

But ExtJS is still dual licensed as (commercial and) `GPL`, and often used in GPL projects. I was wondering, given the popularity, isn't there any other method of constructing the GUI, apart from nerding it together in pure code?

Maybe a plugin for Eclipse or some other wonderful piece of FOSS, like the [Java Window Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)?

We don't need to do everything in the builder, just drafting the GUI. If you want to build an entire webapp in the designer, I think `Sencha Archtect` would be a good choice. But apart from the people who make money with the products and can afford to pay for a commercial license, isn't there a whole community of ExtJS users who use a different (free) builder? And new users, they can learn from the code it spits out and base the rest on that.

Some of my fellow developers have moved to [DHTMLX](http://dhtmlx.com/). It is also dual licenced, similar to ExtJS. It's a lot less advanced, but for simpler tasks it is very usable. And they have a [Visual Composer](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/visualDesigner/index.shtml) online.

I think having a free to use GUI composer/builder is the best choice here. I can see 'new' users choosing DHTMLX over ExtJS nowadays because the ExtJS design tools are behind a pay-wall. Guess who they are going to pay if they ever want to build a commercial product.

But.. ExtJS is definitely more powerful and extendable. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am on the Sencha forums every day and I am not aware of an open source GUI builder that works with Ext4.  There was one built on 2 that supposedly works with three and that may be the one you looked at.  The only option that I am aware of for that type of work is Architect, which is way more advanced than its predecessor Ext Designer and, as you mentioned, is not free or open source.

Comment: Yes architect is much more than just a GUI builder. It's a complete ExtJS IDE as far as I can judge in the 15 minutes I played with it.